# Can't animate Y property of TranslateTransform in Storyboard

Tags: c#, wpf, animation

I'm trying to make a Canvas move up and down, which should be a simple task, but I somehow can't do it:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <TranslateTransform x:Key="transform1" x:Name="testTransform" X="-24" Y="0" />
    <Storyboard x:Key="storyboard1">
        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.4" Storyboard.TargetName="testTransform" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Y" By="6"
            AutoReverse="True" RepeatBehavior="Forever" EasingFunction="{StaticResource ease1}" />
    </Storyboard>
</Window.Resources>
<Window.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource storyboard1}" />
    </EventTrigger>
</Window.Triggers>
[...]
<Canvas x:Name="canvas1" RenderTransform="{StaticResource transform1}">
    <Path Data="{StaticResource amazingPath}" />
</Canvas>
```

Instead of smoothly animating that Canvas, I get this:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll
>
> Additional information: 'testTransform' name cannot be found in the name scope of 'TestProject.MainWindow'.

What's going on here?

Comment: Did you try doing it in blend for visual studio? Usually works well with animations and other things

Comment: I have never used Blend before and would like to continue doing so. Also, that wouldn't help with my question, which is more along the lines of "Why isn't this working in my app", not "Why isn't working in Visual Studio".

Comment: That's not the point. Blend generates xaml for what you are trying to do. You could then inspect the difference and figure out what you are doing differently.

Comment: Alright, I see what you meant. Still, I just tried it, but Blend generates keyframe-driven animations, which are overkill for what I want.

Comment: There are options to change that - i don't know how since i also rarely use it - but in instances like this it's my 2nd option after a brief look at SO. Usually a quick way to find out what you should be doing. After all manually writing xaml to do animations is rather error prone sadly.

Comment: I agree, but since Blend is sh^H^Hnot a good animation tool, doing it by hand is often the only way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works if you set `Storyboard.Target="{StaticResource transform1}"` and if your put the EventTrigger in a Window `Style`:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <TranslateTransform x:Key="transform1" X="-24" Y="0" />
    <Storyboard x:Key="storyboard1">
        <DoubleAnimation
            Duration="0:0:0.4"
            Storyboard.Target="{StaticResource transform1}"
            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Y" By="6"
            AutoReverse="True" RepeatBehavior="Forever" />
    </Storyboard>
</Window.Resources>
<Window.Style>
    <Style TargetType="Window">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
                <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource storyboard1}" />
            </EventTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Style>
<Canvas RenderTransform="{StaticResource transform1}">
    ...
</Canvas>
```

Comment: I won't question why this works in a Style but not in the Window itself, I'll just accept it. I think it's cleaner.

Comment: @PeterW. Honestly, I have no idea about that too. But there is certainly an answer somewhere on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

Set the `Storyboard.TargetName` property to the name of the element (`Canvas`) to which the `TranslateTransform` is applied.

This works:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.Window1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Window.Resources>
        <TranslateTransform x:Key="transform1" x:Name="testTransform" X="-24" Y="0" />
        <Storyboard x:Key="storyboard1">
            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.4" Storyboard.TargetName="canvas1" 
                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.Y" By="6" AutoReverse="True" RepeatBehavior="Forever" />
        </Storyboard>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Window.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource storyboard1}" />
        </EventTrigger>
    </Window.Triggers>
    <Canvas x:Name="canvas1" RenderTransform="{StaticResource transform1}">
        <TextBlock>...</TextBlock>
    </Canvas>
</Window>
```

Comment: While that works, it also means that I'd have to use multiple DoubleAnimations for multiple elements. This can't be the only way.

Comment: Setting Storyboard.TargetName to the Canvas's name works and animates all elements sharing the TranslateTransform. At this point I'm not sure whether this is intended behavior or general WPF weirdness, but whatever, it works. Also, it's really not obvious, or this whole question wouldn't have been necessary.